Freehand Raster Georeferencer can't find a file - so have to force quit QGIS
Using this QGIS plugin I georeferenced three topography rasters (JPG) but the files are on a shared drive, and they've moved or been renamed.
When I launch the project I'm stuck with "Freehand Raster Georeferencer : Image not found" dialogue box and there's no way to continue.

can I recover the rest of the project without these rasters?
is there a way to launch QGIS without certain plugins?
some filenames are non-roman alphabets (so UTF-16 encoded I assume); could this be exacerbating my problem?


You can disable or uninstall the "Freehand Raster Georeferencer" plugin using the Plugins dialog window (menu Plugins->Manage and Install Plugins…).
It is also possible to start QGIS disabling all the plugins just adding --noplugins to the starting command.
Creating and using a new QGIS user profile will also avoid the loading of the "Freehand Raster Georeferencer" plugin.
